# Rails 5 have many through implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many-through

I’m new to Rails. Trying to emplacement has many through association on my application as Users would be able to have to make Stocks though Orders. Currently, I’m getting the error “ First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty”.

Here is my code

**Schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170630092012) do

  create_table "admins", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_admins_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admins_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean "agreement"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "stock_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["stock_id"], name: "index_orders_on_stock_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_orders_on_user_id"
  end

# Could not dump table "stocks" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'fixnum' for column 'product_code'

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

**app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders
  has_many :stocks, through: :orders
end
```

**app/models/stock.rb**

```
class Stock < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders
  has_many :users, through: :orders
end
```

**app/models/order.rb**

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :stock
end
```

**app/controllers/orders_controller.rb**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  # before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:history]

  def history
    @orders = current_user.orders.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def new
    @stock= Stock.new
    @order = @stock.orders.build
    @user = @orders.build_user
  end

  def create
    User.new(user_params)
  end

private

  def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:id, :agreement, :user_id, :stock_id [:id, physician_attributes: [:id ] )
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/stocks_controller.rb**

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!, :except => [:index, :show]

  def index
    @items = Stock.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def new
    @item = current_admin.stocks.new
  end

  def create
    @item = current_admin.stocks.new(stock_params)
    if @item.save
       flash[:notice] = "A #{@item.name} has been listed."
       redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:alart] = "Error: Make sure that you submitting valid information"
    end
  end

  def update
    @item = Stock.find(params[:id])
    if @item.update
      flash[:notice] = "#{@item.name} has been updated."
      render @item
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def show
    find_item
  end

  def edit
    find_item
  end

  def destroy
    find_item
    if @item.destroy
      redirect_to root_path
      flash[:notice] = "#{@item.name} has been deleted."
    else
      flash[:alert] = "#{@item.name} could not be deleted."
    end
  end

  private

  def find_item
    @item = Stock.find(params[:id])
  end

  def stock_params
    params.fetch(:stock).permit(:name, :description, :image, :fixed)
  end
end


views/stocks/_agreement_form.html.erb

<% form_for(@orders) do |order_form| %>
  <p>
    <%= order_form.label :agree %>
    <%= order_form.checkbox :agree %>
    <%= order_form.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: In which file you are rendering `_agreement_form.html.erb` partial?

Comment: @Pavan from stocks/show.html.erb

Comment: Post your `stocks_controller`

Answer (score 0):

```
def show
  find_item
  @order = @item.orders.build
end
```

I think you should update `<% form_for(@orders) do |order_form| %>` it should use `@order`.

Comment: And `find_item` should be in before action rather than calling it in actions.